# Прозрачность для header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть контейнер header в котором расположена навигация и лого.Когда задаю opacity то все элементы становятся прозрачными.Как сделать так чтобы прозрачным был только background????

```css
.site-header{
 color: var(--BgColor);
 height: 140px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: var(--GeneralColor);
 opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="head-wrap fw-row-container">
   <div class="site-branding fw-col-lg-3 fw-col-md-3 fw-col-sm-4 ">
    <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
     <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php
    
    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
     <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
    <?php
    endif; ?>
   </div><!-- .site-branding -->
   <nav class="main-navigation fw-col-lg-8 fw-col-lg-offset-1 fw-col-md-9 fw-col-sm-8 ">
    <i id="menu-btn" class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php
     wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
      'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
     ) );
    ?>
   </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  </div><!-- #masthead -->
 </header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно для задания цвет воспользоваться `rgba`. Например, `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`, где 0.5 - степень прозрачности.

Comment: @ Stepan Kasyanenko а можно это как то сделать что бы цвет не терялся, просто цвет задан в переменных

Comment: Да, можно пишите `background-color: rgba(var(--GeneralColor),0.5);`/Цвет должен быть в `rgb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать фон в формате rgba.
Возьми цвет из переменной и переведи его в rgba.

Еще можно костылем сделать - в header сделать отдельный блок `.header__background` и применить `opacity` к нему. Но на практике такое хуже, чем просто цвет в rgba перевести.

Answer (score 1):

пример корявый, но суть идеи я думаю полностью поймешь, сделай такой же блок как header у тебя и задай opacity ему

```css
.site-header {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.site-header2 {
  z-index: -111;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=eda8902b40a4767bf872b0ec3fe02af1&n=13) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="site-header2"></div>
  остальное не будет наследовать opacity
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дочерние элементы наследуют значение родителя. Вам нужно просто взять блок создать внутри header, сделать в нём bg и растянуть его по высоте и ширине родителя. Вот и всё.